# How to setup PPTP-VPN on ubuntu and how to run?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, internet, cable, pptp

I was using my cable internet on windows and it was working. Now I moved to ubuntu for development work. But I am unable to connect this internet on ubuntu. I called their technical support and they ask me to install PPTP (I have forgot the exact name) and then provide our server name, my username and passowrd.

I downloaded(from windows internet) PPTP debian and install it but I did not find it after installation. From where can I use this client??

can someone tell me that how to install PPTP on ubuntu without internet and how to run this software and how to use?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure they weren't looking for PPPOE (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol_over_Ethernet).  It is far more likely that an ISP wants you to use PPPOE.

Comment: My networking concepts are very weak. Can you explain your point please? Their server is windows based and I am using ubuntu. They have their own software to connect to their internet for windows but not for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a world of difference between PPTP (Point to Point Tunnelling Protocol) and PPPoE (Point to Point Protocol over Ethernet).  PPPoE is the one most commonly used by ISPs.  I'd suggest you call your ISP and check which they mean as what you need to do will be very different.

It would probably help too if you could mention your ISP.